# MySQL Full Text search '+this +week' not working as intended

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm trying to use FULL-Text search with my database to speed up the results but it doesn't seem to work properly:

For example, the following query returns no result

```
select * FROM data WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+this +week' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

When this one returns results:

```
select * FROM data WHERE name like '%this%week%'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: There are many rows where name starts with `'this week'`.

Comment: Please show us some sample data to make your question talkative.

Comment: `this` is one off the FULLTEXT  ["stopwords"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) for the InnoDB engine and MyISAM engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both expressions are *not* equivalent:

- the full text feature searches for words, while `LIKE` with the `%` special character basically searches for any part of the field
- another difference is that full text search allows words in any sequence, while `LIKE` requests that words follow the order given in the pattern

When using full-text search, MySQL deliberately ignores a pre-defined list of very common words, called *stopwords* : as you would suspect, `this` is one of them. This is probably what is preventing your value to match. You would need to remove this word from your search. See [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) for a list of MySQL full-text stopwords (or just query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD`).

---

Consider the following dataset:

```
select * from mytable;

| id  | name                    |
| --- | ----------------------- |
| 1   | this happened last week |
| 2   | last week this happened |
| 3   | thishappenedlastweek    |
| 4   | this happens this week  |
```

When filtering using `LIKE`:

```
select * from mytable where name like '%this%week%';

| id  | name                    |
| --- | ----------------------- |
| 1   | this happened last week |
| 3   | thishappenedlastweek    |
| 4   | this happens this week  |
```

With full-text search and stopword  `'this'`, nothing is returned:

```
select *
FROM mytable
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+this +week' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

There are no results to be displayed.
```

This would work when removing the stopword:

```
select *
FROM mytable
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+week' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

| id  | name                    |
| --- | ----------------------- |
| 1   | this happened last week |
| 2   | last week this happened |
| 4   | this happens this week  |
```

Combinations not including stopwords do work, too:

```
select *
FROM mytable
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+happened +week' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

| id  | name                    |
| --- | ----------------------- |
| 1   | this happened last week |
| 2   | last week this happened |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x7Gkk6a3JEBevtVzj9s8cR/4)**.